Apply an outer join on external data set against a table with read access only?
I have an external data set.



Column A
Column B




a1
b1


a2
b2



There is a table I want to apply an outer join against.



Column A
Column B
Column C




a1
b2
c3


a2
b2
c4



I have read access only and cannot create a table in the system. How can I get to a result like this



Column A
Column B
Column C




a1
b1
NULL


a2
b2
c4



I tried doing this with a where statement against the table but for instances with no match the lines are not pulled. I require to maintain the unmatched lines with an NULL indicator.

You mention an "external data set", but you didn't specify the source.    That said, take a peek at openrowset

select ot.ColumnA, ot.ColumnB, it.ColumnC from externaldatatable ot left join internaltable it on ot.columnA = it.columnA and ot.ColumnB = it.columnB what's the problem?
